# Seg fault when using cv::split

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, gpu

Here is my code:

```
    printf("preallocations\n");
    char * addr = (char *) bo_gc320->m_fb_id[gc320_buf_idx];
    cv::Mat src(cvSize(bo_gc320->m_width, bo_gc320->m_height), CV_8UC4, addr);
    cv::Mat alpha(cvSize(bo_gc320->m_width, bo_gc320->m_height), CV_8UC1);
    cv::Mat rgb(cvSize(bo_gc320->m_width, bo_gc320->m_height), CV_8UC3);
    cv::Mat dst(cvSize(bo_gc320->m_width, bo_gc320->m_height), CV_8UC3);
    printf("postallocations\n");

    cv::Mat * out = new cv::Mat[4];// malloc(4*sizeof(cv::Mat *));
    for (int k=0;k<4;k++) {
      out[k] = cv::Mat(cvSize(bo_gc320->m_width, bo_gc320->m_height), CV_8UC1);
      printInfo(out[k]);
    }
    printf("presplit\n");
    printInfo(src);
    cv::split(src, out);
    printf("postsplit\n");
```

and the output is:

```
preallocations
postallocations
dim(332, 768)unsigned char(1)
dim(332, 768)unsigned char(1)
dim(332, 768)unsigned char(1)
dim(332, 768)unsigned char(1)
presplit
dim(332, 768)unsigned char(4)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am printing the info about the arrays in a helper function. The data in addr is coming from the output buffer of a gc320 GPU. Could this be caused by the addr not containing valid data?

Comment: Please read [mre], then [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that addr was actually invalid data and was not filling the whole CV_8UC4 Mat struct. Once I changed the buffer, the problem was solved.